# Is it more efficient to perform a LINQ in a foreach statement?

Tags: c#, loops, linq, foreach, collections

Do these statements do the same exact thing?

```
var listA = someList.TakeWhile(predicate);
foreach(var item in listA)
{
    /// perform code here
}
```

versus...

```
foreach(var item in someList.TakeWhile(predicate))
{
    /// perform some code here
}
```

Is the collection created first and then iterated through O(N^2)? Or is the collection iterated through as its being created O(N)?

Comment: Yes. `.TakeWhile` returns a new `IEnumerable`, it *doesn't* enumerate anything immediately. Assigning to a local variable vs using a temporary value on the stack wouldn't make any difference.

Comment: no difference, but i would go to `var listA = someList.TakeWhile(predicate)` for reusability and readability

Comment: FYI: https://sharplab.io/#v2:EYLgZgpghgLgrgJwgZwLQBsD2BjK7VhwB22MAlpkarDAmcHDCgDQAmIA1AD4ACATAEYAsACgeABgAEPAQDoAMmSIBHANyiJ0gQBZ1IjQGZpfSQGFJAb1GSb0oz22SAsgAoAlJeu3vi5DAA8SjAAfJLImAC2EL4wkgC8kkQQAO6SMYFEIe563t48AKwZMMySwJiY6KEADkisZLhM8ZJk8aG0cBA5uTYAblAIkuhkfgCCTeFRMbIAKlAA1hAA6gAWZOgQLjUQdQ0Qbl3dYJhIUNjLLn0DZEwRzUSDwzAjbl7dViLd3QD0P5JVEAgjghbthMKwIJJlgCIK9cgBfWEIj62WE8eyOABy7k8yO66SCoQm0UeTSSqXxmWC2VheUKQRKZQq1Vq9VgEISLTibQQHQOuSB0DOF36zRudzCkWJfhm8yWq3WmxZuzcL1xuXen1yPy+fwBQNuRMkoPBkOhNNsSO8SLhQA

Comment: Can't upvote these comments, but they're all great. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Jeremy Lakeman provided the right answer in comments.

The type of the variable `listA` in:

```cs
var listA = someList.TakeWhile(predicate);
```

is `IEnumerable<T>`, T being the type of an individual element of your collection `someList`. This is clearly shown by the signature of the `TakeWhile` method:

```
public static System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<TSource> TakeWhile<TSource> (this System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<TSource> source, Func<TSource,int,bool> predicate);
```

as can be seen at the [`TakeWhile` documentation page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.takewhile?view=net-6.0).

Declaring a variable of type `IEnumerable<T>` doesn't enumerate it.
To enumerate an `IEnumerable`, you have to do it explicitly, by enumerating it if a `foreach` loop for instance, or by using it to produce a new materialized collection, such as a `List`, `Dictionary`, etc... by calling methods such `.ToList()` or `ToDictionary()`, etc...

This is explicitly stated in the (for instance) [`ToList` documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.tolist?view=net-6.0#remarks):

> The `ToList<TSource>(IEnumerable<TSource>)` method forces immediate
> query evaluation and returns a `List<T>` that contains the query
> results. You can append this method to your query in order to obtain a
> cached copy of the query results. `ToArray` has similar behavior but
> returns an array instead of a `List<T>`.

So in both your code examples, the `IEnumerable` you construct will be enumerated only once in the `foreach` loop.

Also: even if you had materialized your collection before enumerating it:

```
var listA = someList
    .TakeWhile(predicate)
    .ToList(); // Notice the .ToList() call that forces the enumeration.

foreach(var item in listA)
{
    /// perform code here
}
```

It would still be an O(n) operation, not an O(n^2).
If you take N elements from your `someList` collection, you will enumerate them once with the `.ToList()` call, and once in the `foreach`loop, for a total of 2 x N, not N^2.

Comment: Appreciate the thorough response, it answered some other questions I had as well. Just one question for clarification on Big-O notation, in the worst case scenario (where .TakeWhile returns the original collection) would this function not be O(n^2) because it essentially performs two for-loops over the whole collection?

Comment: Roughly, to have O(n^2), the second loop needs to be nested into the first one. So that on each step of the N steps the first loop, you perforn the M steps of the second one, totaling NxM steps in total, which can be O(n^2).
Here the two loops are independent, not nested.

Comment: Perfect explanation, thanks for the clarification

Answer (score 1):

Both forms are same. According to Microsoft documentation the query (`TakeWhile`) won't execute until its `GetEnumerator` method is called directly or by foreach.

> The query represented by this method is not executed until the object is enumerated either by calling its `GetEnumerator` method directly or by using `foreach` in Visual C# or `For Each` in Visual Basic.

[source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.takewhile?view=net-5.0)